# Running Hive on Ubuntu getting error when running show tables; Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive

Configuration Ubuntu 20.04
Hadoop/Hive with Postgresql

My hive-site.xml which I got from [https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_ig_hive_metastore_configure.html]

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/metastore</value>
</property>
 
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
</property>
 
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hiveuser</value>
</property>
 
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>mypassword</value>
</property>
 
<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://127.0.0.1:9083</value>
  <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
```

The full error I get is:
hive> show tables;
FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

I tried setting up using a Derby with the same success so I changed to Postgres thinking it might serve me better. I was wrong so far.
I'd prefer to stick with Postgres but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have shared is from Hive CLI. Can you also look for any errors in Hive Metastore service as well?

Also can you try running Hive CLI `hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console` for more logs.